# Как протестировать Laravel Socialite google аутентификацию , без наличия доменного имени или на локальном сервере?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth2, google-oauth2

Использую Laravel socialite, для google аутентификации, как без доменного  имени протестировать его,

Нужно протестировать работу, или на локальном сервере, или на хостинге, на хостинге только ip адрес сайта, без доменного имени.

Как лучше всего это сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите протестировать на локальном сервере, то укажите `http://localhost:8000/test`